# This-pointer capture in lambda wrapper around recursive function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, this-pointer

I have a class template `Wrap<T>` with a recursive member function `test(int)` that I want to pass to an STL algorithm with a lambda (`std::accumulate` in the code below).

If I use a default capture list of `=`, and make my recursive meber function `static`, all is fine and get the result I want.

However, if I make it a non-static member function, both Visual C++ and gcc 4.7.2 complain about an unitialized `this`-pointer, unless I qualify my recursive call as `this->test()`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct Wrap 
{
   static int test1(int depth)
   {
      std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
      return depth == 0? 1 : std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), int(0), [=](int sub, int const&) {
         return sub + test1(depth - 1);
      });   
   }

   int test2(int depth)
   {
      std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
      return depth == 0? 1 : std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), int(0), [=](int sub, int const&) {
         return sub + /*this->*/test2(depth - 1);
      });   
   }   
};

int main()
{
   std::cout << Wrap<int>::test1(0) << "\n"; // 1
   std::cout << Wrap<int>::test1(1) << "\n"; // 4
   std::cout << Wrap<int>::test1(2) << "\n"; // 16

   Wrap<int> w;
   std::cout << w.test2(0) << "\n"; // 1
   std::cout << w.test2(1) << "\n"; // 4
   std::cout << w.test2(2) << "\n"; // 16
}
```

Output on [LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/dGesb%2419):

```
source.cpp: In instantiation of 'int Wrap<T>::test2(int) [with T = int]':   
source.cpp:32:26:   required from here 
source.cpp:19:74: error: missing initializer for member 'Wrap<T>::test2(int) [with T = int]::<lambda(int, const int&)>::__this' [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
```

Uncommenting the `/*this->/*` piece, gives the same result as for the static member function.

**Why do I need to qualify my recursive call with `this->`?**

Comment: I am trying your example and it seems to compile both with Clang 3.2 and GCC 4.7.2 (even on liveworkspace)...

Comment: @AndyProwl it gives a warning and does not compile with -Werror

Comment: I see. I am now trying on MinGW (GCC 4.7.1) and it does not even see `test1`

Comment: it seems to me this is not related with lambdas, but with name lookup in a template

Comment: @AndyProwl you might be right about name lookup, but it is lambda-specific becuase writing `std::accumulate` as an explicit for loop does not give any warnings/errors

Comment: yes, you are correct. i believe this is a bug. from the text of the warning/error, it seems the lambda closure type does contain a `__this` member which captures the `this` pointer, but that member is not initialized in the closure's constructor

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug. With some small changes (adding an include for `<numeric>`, modifying `std::vector` to not use an initializer list), VS2012 compiles this just fine without the `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a bug of GCC 4.7.2. The warning says:

`missing initializer for member 'Wrap<T>::test2(int) [with T = int]::<lambda(int, const int&)>::__this'`

Which means that the compiler recognizes the `this` pointer is to be captured and the generated closure does contain a pointer for it, but that pointer does not get initialized in the closure's constructor.

This is confirmed by the fact that attempting to access/change a member variable (which is not present in your example, but can be easily added) causes a run-time error. For instance, this shows no output at liveworkspace.org

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct Wrap 
{
    int test2(int depth)
    {
        m_test++;
        std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
        return depth == 0? 1 : std::accumulate(
             v.begin(), v.end(), int(0), [=](int sub, int const&) {
             return sub + /*this->*/test2(depth - 1);
             });   
    }

    int m_test = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Wrap<int> w;
    std::cout << w.test2(2) << "\n"; // 1
}
```

This code compiles fine with Clang 3.2 and VS2012, which seems to confirm the presence of a bug.

Comment: Further, `g++ 4.7.1` under MinGW actually chokes on `static int test1`.

Comment: @Yuushi: indeed, i mentioned that in a comment

Comment: Ah, so you did, I didn't even see it.